# How to navigate to implementing class from interface in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Suppose I have:

```
interface Foo {
  void doStuff();
}

class FooImpl implements Foo {
  public void doStuff() {
    // stuff
  }
 }
```

When I see `myFoo.doStuff()` in my code, if my cursor is over `doStuff()`, pressing F3 will take me to the `doStuff()` method in the interface `Foo`. Of course, I often am much more interested in the implementation of this method, not just the signature.

Does Eclipse have an easy way to navigate from a declaration of a method in an interface to the implementation of that method in the implementing class?

In my case, there will not be ambiguity about what the implementing class is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Highlight the method name, and press either <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> or <kbd>F4</kbd>.  You'll see a type hierarchy, but linked to the method rather than the containing classes.  Select the desired implementation class.

Comment: F4 shows more or less the same thing but in an actual view, rather than kind of a "popup". You might prefer one or the other.

Answer (score 7):

Or - if you have enabled Hyperlinking (see the preference page with that name) - you can press Control (or Command on MacOS) and click on the method name. It will then show a menu with "Open Declaration" and "Open Implementation"...

Comment: Hah, I don't know how I always missed this dialog. Just made CTRL + click, which selects open declaration.

Answer (score 3):

Select the method and press Ctrl+T.

Also clicking the `gray` up-arrow on the left hand side of the editor close to the line numbers will take you to a method declaration in an interface. If that same arrow is `green`, it will take you to a method definition in a super class.