# How to navigate to implementing class from generic interface in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

Very similar question to [How to navigate to implementing class from interface in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430825/how-to-navigate-to-implementing-class-from-interface-in-eclipse)
Except add in generics.  Consider the following:

```
interface Foo<T> {
  void doStuff(T obj);
}

class FooImpl implements Foo<String> {
  public void doStuff(String obj) {
    // stuff
  }
}

class FooStringClient {
  private Foo<String> foo;
}
```

If I'm looking at FooStringClient, how can I find implementations of Foo<String>?  The answers to that other question would show me all implementations of Foo<T> for all T.  If there are many implementations of Foo<T> for various T, visually scanning the list to find only the Foo<String> implementations is rough.

Comment: Not sure there is a way given how the type system works, but it's an interesting question and if there is an answer I'd like to hear about it as well so +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=162062) marked WONTFIX which requests just this feature.